# Modal in angular lets user click out of it

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog in my angularJS app, but when the user clicks on the greyed out site behind the modal, the modal closes. I want the modal to behave like a modal, ie, you have to respond to what's inside in order to get it to close. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? Here is a jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/aDuJIku/2/edit

EDIT: Code for future reference:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app='ModalDemo'>
  <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <button ng-click='toggleModal()'>Open Modal Dialog</button>
    <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='400px' height='60%'>
      <p>Modal Content Goes here<p>
    </modal-dialog>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

app = angular.module('ModalDemo', []);
app.directive('modalDialog', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true, // Replace with the template below
    transclude: true, // we want to insert custom content inside the directive
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      if (attrs.width)
        scope.dialogStyle.width = attrs.width;
      if (attrs.height)
        scope.dialogStyle.height = attrs.height;
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div><div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'><div class='ng-modal-close' ng-click='hideModal()'>X</div><div class='ng-modal-dialog-content' ng-transclude></div></div></div>"
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.modalShown = false;
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.modalShown = !$scope.modalShown;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: plz post your code from jsbin along with the question. In case if the link expires in future...it should be still available to user who visit this question in future

Comment: Good point, edited above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this section of your directive's template, remove *ng-click='hideModal()'* and you're done.

```
<div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap set the backdrop to static.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/App/Documents/Templates/DeleteDocumentDialogTemplate.html',
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```